# What kind of device is this LT6251 MBR...CT?

Tags: identification, device

Can't find any specs on this device (LT 6251 MBR10100CT or is it MBR|0|00CT or MBRI0I00CT). Can't find datasheet for it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a dual common-cathode Schottky barrier rectifier. Both Vishay and Diodes Incorporated have the device as "MBR10100CT", although neither uses the exact package marking as shown in the photo.

Comment: Thanks. It's it. Googling for "MBR10100CT" gives datasheet.